# Is there a constructible flat pairing function?

Tags: set-theory

In ZFC set theory, is there a Skolem function f such that ZFC can prove f is a flat pairing function? And if so, can someone explicitly give me a formula?

Comment: What do you mean, "$z$ is a flat pairing function of $x$ and $y$?" A pairing function, flat or not, is a *proper class*; and for any $x, y, z$ of infinite rank such that $rk(z)=\max\{rk(x), rk(y)\}$, we can define a flat pairing function according to which $\langle x, y\rangle =z$, so the "local" version of the question is trivial.

Comment: @Noah Schweber I have edited the question.

Comment: Doesn’t the [Quine-Rosser definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Quine-Rosser_definition) work?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott So, what is the explicit formula? Abbreviations in the formula are fine as long as you define them beforehand.

Comment: @user107952: It appears to me that expanding the definition given at the link to whatever degree of detail you want is a routine, if tedious, task.

Comment: Using the Kuratowski definition, prove there is an injection $V\times V\to V$ which respects infinite ranks (for finite ranks this is impossible, of course). Then use this definition as the new ordered pairs, which are now flat as a duck. Bonus points for avoiding choice.

Comment: Okay, to be really precise, this is my question: Is there an open formula P(x,y,z) such that 1) ZFC proves For all x and y, there exists a unique z such that P(x,y,z) 2) ZFC proves For all x, y, x', y' and z, if P(x,y,z) and P(x', y', z) then x = x' and y= y'. and 3) ZFC proves For all x and y and all infinite cardinals c, if x is of rank c and y is of rank c, and P(x,y,z), then z is of rank c.

Comment: @AsafKaragila . . . are ducks, in fact, flat?

Comment: @Noah: Well, when elephants stomp on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joel David Hamkins' answer to this mathoverflow question - https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62790/kuratowskis-definition-of-ordered-pairs - gives a description of a flat pairing function which is easily (if really, really tediously) unwound to a first-order formula. It is straightforward to check that $ZF$ proves that this is a flat pairing function.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Quine-Rosser_definition.