# Is there an flat unordered pairing function in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory

Is there an unordered pairing function that does not increase rank whenever the max rank is infinite, in ZFC? An unordered pairing function is one such that $f(x,y)=f(z,w)$ iff $(x=z \wedge y=w) \vee (x=w \wedge y=z)$.

Comment: Do you want $\exists x,y\colon \operatorname{rk}(f(x,y))\le\max\operatorname{rk}(x),\operatorname{rk}(x)\}$? Or $\forall x,y\colon \max\operatorname{rk}(x),\operatorname{rk}(x)\}\ge\omega\to \operatorname{rk}(f(x,y))\le\max\operatorname{rk}(x),\operatorname{rk}(x)\}$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a constructible flat pairing function?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1335249/is-there-a-constructible-flat-pairing-function). To be more precise: Joel Hamkins provided a positive [answer at math overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62790/kuratowskis-definition-of-ordered-pairs).

Comment: @Stefan I don't think it's a duplicate - that flat pairing function isn't *unordered*, and it's not trivial to turn it into an unordered pairing function.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Presumably the latter, otherwise it's trivial.

Comment: @Noah Oh, I should have read the question more carefully. I totally missed the "un" - twice!. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Stefan You can retract the close vote (if you haven't already, I can't tell).

Comment: @Idisagree How exactly do I do this? I wasn't able to find an answer in the help center or via Google, yet.

Comment: @Stefan, if you click "close" again it will give you the option to retract your close vote.

Comment: @Noah I've tried that, but it doesn't allow me to select this option again. It is greyed out and says "you have already raised this type of flag" in red below. If I attempt to click it, nothing happens.

Comment: So when you click it again, at the bottom right of the window it should say "retract close vote."

Comment: Why did this get closed as a duplicate? It's *not* the same question. It is true that we can get from a flat pairing function to an unordered flat pairing function fairly easily, but it's not trivial in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's look at the special case when $x\cap y=\emptyset$.

Here, we can define a *disjoint unordered pairing function*: $\langle x, y\rangle_d=\{[a, b]: a, b\in x\}\cup\{[c, d]: c, d\in y\}$, where $[\cdot, \cdot]$ is the flat (*ordered*) pairing function of your choice. The point is that from $\langle x, y\rangle_d$ we can recover the set of elements of $x\cup y$, and moreover tell when two elements "belong together" - and this is enough to determine $x$ and $y$, up to swapping.

In general, we can do the following: for $x, y$ sets, let $$\langle x, y\rangle=[\langle x-y, y-x\rangle_d, x\cap y].$$ I believe this works.

Comment: @GME, you're quite right - fixed.